# Combining rather than Appending XML

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a series of main and supplemental XML files that I need to combine in memory for reference. Thus far I have been using an AppendChild approach, and it works, but it is inelegant and when the time comes that I decide I want to save a combined file it really starts to be an issue.

So, in simplified form, I have this...

```
$mainXml = [xml]'<Definitions>
    <Sets>
        <Set id="Test">
            <Package>Main</Package>
        </Set>
    </Sets>
    <Packages>
        <Package id="Main">
            <Rollout>
                <Machine>
                    <Enroll id="Enroll" />
                </Machine>
                <User>
                </User>
            </Rollout>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Definitions>'

$supplamentalXml = [xml]'<Definitions>
    <Sets>
        <Set id="Supplamental">
            <Package>Supplamental</Package>
        </Set>
    </Sets>
    <Packages>
        <Package id="Supplamental">
            <Rollout>
                <Machine>
                    <Enroll id="Enroll" />
                </Machine>
                <User>
                </User>
            </Rollout>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Definitions>'

$finalXml = $mainXml

foreach ($node in $supplamentalXml.DocumentElement.ChildNodes) {
    $finalXml.DocumentElement.AppendChild($finalXml.ImportNode($node, $true)) > $null
}
```

Which results in XML like this...

```
<Definitions>
  <Sets>
    <Set id="Test">
      <Package>Main</Package>
    </Set>
  </Sets>
  <Packages>
    <Package id="Main">
      <Rollout>
        <Machine>
          <Enroll id="Enroll" />
        </Machine>
        <User>
        </User>
      </Rollout>
    </Package>
  </Packages>
  <Sets>
    <Set id="Supplamental">
      <Package>Supplamental</Package>
    </Set>
  </Sets>
  <Packages>
    <Package id="Supplamental">
      <Rollout>
        <Machine>
          <Enroll id="Enroll" />
        </Machine>
        <User />
      </Rollout>
    </Package>
  </Packages>
</Definitions>
```

That works, as I can then use XPath SelectNodes to get Sets and I will get both sets. But some part of me thinks it would be better to have the resultant XML organized "correctly", thus...

```
<Definitions>
  <Sets>
    <Set id="Test">
      <Package>Main</Package>
    </Set>
    <Set id="Supplamental">
      <Package>Supplamental</Package>
    </Set>
  </Sets>
  <Packages>
    <Package id="Main">
      <Rollout>
        <Machine>
          <Enroll id="Enroll" />
        </Machine>
        <User>
        </User>
      </Rollout>
    </Package>
    <Package id="Supplamental">
      <Rollout>
        <Machine>
          <Enroll id="Enroll" />
        </Machine>
        <User />
      </Rollout>
    </Package>
  </Packages>
</Definitions>
```

However, the actual content of the files is much more complicated than this, and I haven't found a built in mechanism to just append in nodes, rather than appending and repeating whole nodes. So, I guess my first question is, am I just being ridiculous in wanting the XML in memory to be structured this way? Is there any resource or performance argument one way or the other? Total XML is still pretty small. A few hundred K on disk for the most part, but I can see this changing with time. And, assuming there is no built in mechanism to combine rather than just append, I would have to write my own code, which means more coding time, more potential bugs, and more processing time. And again, perhaps for no real world value.

Additionally, where I to ever export this XML, I dislike the fact that the source XML uses the four spaces indent default of NotePad ++, but the synthesized XML is two space. Not a big deal if the XML is never read by humans, but ideally I would prefer to emit well formatted XML. I know PSCX includes a formatter, but I would rather not have additional dependencies. And I have used System.IO.StringWriter for screen output, but I have not groked an easy way to use it to format XML ready to save.

One last note. Sadly, both questions are in the context of PS v2, as I am not in a position to enforce a newer version at the moment. If there is a super slick way to do it in a newer version I might do the formatting conditionally, but I would love to be able to address both issues in v2 if possible.

Again, the whole issue is borderline academic, as FUNCTIONALLY what I have works. I am just wondering if there is a performance reasons to change, or not change. And if there is, is it an easy built in PowerShell cmdlet away, or is it a bunch of custom code away?